# Получение декодированного json по ссылке с параметром

Tags: php

**Предисловие**

Есть несколько страниц, в которые нужно выводить данные из json, к каждой странице свой json.
В данный момент страницы две, но может быть больше, из-за этого решил вынести получение и декодирование json в отдельный файл и подключать как `include`.

Т.к. я дуб-дубом в php, то подумал что каждый раз создавать `include`, с определённой ссылкой, для каждой из страниц не выгодно, по этом решил создать только один, но в ссылке `inclide` указывать параметр, который равен названию нужного json.

**Получилось следующее**

В одной из страниц:

```
inclide('../res/json/get_json.php?json=work');
```

В `get_json.php`

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  // По моей логике, происходит следующее.
  $t = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  // ↑↑↑ парсим урл текущего запроса, да?
  parse_str($t['query'], $jq);
  // ↑↑↑ получаем параметры отпарсенного урл
  $jf = @file_get_contents('../res/json/'.$jq['json'].'.json');
  // ↑↑↑ получаем файл, из запроса урл на файл будет /res/json/work.json, так ведь?
  $json = json_decode($jf, true);
  // ну и декодируем полученный json
?>
```

Далее я хотел на `одной из страниц`, использовать сразу вывод данных из json, допустим `$json['param']`, ибо `$json = json_decode()`..
Но связи с тем, что я очень слаб в php, я получил следующие ошибки:

> Warning: include(/res/json/get_json.php?json=work): failed to open stream: No error in *одна из страниц* on line (строка с inclide`)
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/res/json/get_json.php?json=work' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:/openserver/ospanel/modules/php/PHP-5.6;c:/openserver/ospanel/modules/php/PHP-5.6/PEAR/pear') in *одна из страниц* on line (строка с include)

Что хочу узнать от вас:
1. Почему данный код не работает, где косяк?
2. Можно ли его "починить" и стоит ли? Вдруг есть альтернатива "проверенее".

Comment: Значение параметра json, у get-запроса, можете получить сразу, из супермассива без парсинга, вот так:```$_GET["json"]```

Comment: У include аргумент неверный -лишний суффикс `?json=work`

Comment: Может стоит почитать про php и как он соотносится с web, чем писать такую дичь?

Comment: @ArchDemon, может стоит воздерживаться от комментариев, а не писать какую-то дичь?

Comment: @Jigius, спасибо за информацию, буду знать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно лучше в этом случае в get_json.php описать функцию, типа

```
function get_json($name) {
   $basePath = '/путь/на/диске/до/папки/с/jsonами/';
   $filePath = $basePath.$name.'.json';
   if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
      return false;
   }
   return json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath));
}
```

А внутри файла, где надо получить json

```
require 'get_json.php';
$data = get_json('work');
```

Comment: Блэн.. Действительно, почему я сразу не додумался использовать `function`, спасибо)